# Comparing 2 solutions of problem 2 chapter 0 of Allen Hatcher.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, definition, deformation-theory, retraction

The question is to construct an explicit deformation retraction of $\mathbb{R^n} - \{0\}$ onto $S^{n-1}.$

Here is the answers I found online so far:

The first solution:

> [image]

The second solution

> [image]

**Here are my questions:**

1- Is the first answer correct? Is it proving that there is a weak deformation retract? Is the second answer correct? Is it proving that there is a strong deformation retract instead?

2- I do not understand really the difference between the definition of a weak deformation retract and a strong deformation retract when I am trying to prove them. could anyone explain this for me please?

Here is the definition of SDR from AT:

> [image]

And here is the definition of WDR from Rotman:

> [image]

And here is the definition of SDR from Rotman:

> [image]

Could anyone help me clarify these descripencies please?

Comment: I think the difference is that the homotopy in the strong deformation retract must fix the image of $A$ throughout the entire transformation of $X$, whereas the weak deformation retract doesn't.

Comment: @BobJones sorry I did not understand what you said ... could you clarify more please?

Comment: The answer is easy -- what Hatcher called "deformation retract", is in other sources usually called "strong deformation retract" (that is, $H_t$ is identity on $A$). Weak deformation retract does not require this condition.

Comment: What about my other questions about the 2 solutions above @PeterFranek

Comment: Sorry I'm confused about what is "first" and "second" answer? The map $f_t$ is a strong deformation retract and hence of course a (weak) deformation retract.

Comment: How the proof of the WDR should take place? why we define a homotopy in the proof of WDR then?

Comment: @PeterFranek okay sorry I will edit my post to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Hatcher's definition of DF is a bit stronger than the usual definition. Let's take [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)#Deformation_retract_and_strong_deformation_retract) as a reference -- it coincides with Rotman definition. In this sense, $f_t$ is a deformation retract if $f_t$ has properties (1), (2), (3) and property (4) for $t=1$. The SDF according to wiki-definition ("DF" for Hatcher) requires (4) for **all** $t$.

So yes, your first solution shows DF in the usual sense, and your second solution shows SDF if you assume "for all $t$" in point (4).